# How do I find the OrderID value in OpenCart?

Tags: php, tracking, opencart, affiliate

I have connected my OpenCart with an Affiliate network.

In order for me to link and have orders tracked they require the following information on the tracking code; the `OrderID` and the `OrderValue` the `( Sub Total) without delivery`

I can't find what value the OrderID and the Sub Total has in OpenCart.

I need to insert these values in the code below.

OrderValue = Subtotal

```
<iframe src="http://track.xxx.com/?trackID=[IdFrånCookie]&orderValue=[orderValue]&orderID=[orderID]&programID=319" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
```

I have tried with `column_order_id` in the [orderID] but that did not work.

Does any one know which values I should input?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your post to make it more readable. You could try:

1 - Open footer.tpl (catalog/view/theme/default/common/footer.tpl)

At the bottom add the code like:

```
<?
    // calculate totals
    $subTotalShow=$current_item_price;
    $addDel=$subTotalShow+4.95;
    $total=round($addDel, 2); // show decimal places
?>
<?php foreach ($orders as $order)
// only will run now if logged in and order has been complete
// so basically on completion of an order { ?>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
                <iframe src="http://track.xxx.com/?trackID=inpbox&orderValue=[<?=$total?>]&orderID=[<?=$text_order_id?>]&programID=319"
                scrolling="no"
                frameborder="0"
                width="1"
                height="1"></iframe>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Although I am not fully sure this code will work. I expect edits but I will keep it on my watch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Are you sure i should put it in footer.tpl? The affiliate network says it must be in confirm.php. I got this error message when i have it in confirm.php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /hermes/bosweb/web094/b944/ipg.inpbox/xxx.com/catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php on line 417. Located at catalog/controller/checkout/